# How do I de-attach an ESEA account from my steam account?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to get ESEA, but unforunately I signed up for it a while ago with my email address and steam account. It looks like you can only log in with your accounts Alias, and I cannot remember mine. I've tried searching for accounts with my old names and can't find a thing either.

When I try to sign up with a new email, it says my steam account is in use. How do I de-activate my ESEA account with my steam account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first recommend [trying to reset your password](https://play.esea.net/index.php?s=upanel&d=lostpass) and see if it includes an alias. Personalised emails may include it in the header or the subject line.

If that does not work, there does not seem to be an obvious way to recover an alias, so I would suggest shooting a ticket to [their support team](https://play.esea.net/index.php?s=support&d=tickets). You probably should include your steam id, which you could do, for example, [here](https://steamidfinder.com/). They may be able to help you further.

I doubt they would be able to disassociate your ESEA account from your Steam account, because it would open the door for cheaters to just create a new ESEA account when they are caught, invalidating any ban ESEA could provide.